i am working a fluxstore app template to my own app and it says like below
 [⌛️Slow-139514ms]CACHE ISSUE: ClientException with SocketException: Connection timed out (OS Error: Connection timed out, errno = 110), address = buildingmartethio.com, port = 52184, uri=https://buildingmartethio.com/wp-json/wc/v2/products/tags?per_page=9&page=1&hide_empty=true&lang=en&consumer_key=ck_xxxxxxxxxxxxx&consumer_secret=cs_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
i want to change to my ecommerce website to this app how can i make it
i tried to change the website name and category the website connection is fine but the categories did not fetch to app screen
